# Увеличение переменной с input кнопкой - кастомный вариант?

Tags: javascript, html5

Как реализовать нативным JavaScript,
чтобы я брал переменную с input и ещё увеличивал по клику на единицу?
Обычный input type="number" не подходит, потому что нужно кастомизировать, и я хочу написать с нуля.

```js
const input=document.getElementsByTagName('input')
input.innerHTML = 1

const btn=document.getElementsByTagName('button')
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  input++
})
```

```html
<input type="number" width="50px" >
<button>Incement</button>
```

Comment: Так дело не пойдёт. Забрали галочку - значит, мой ответ Вам не подошёл - удаляю. Хотя, уже сделал третью доработку, о которой Вы просили.

Comment: ммммммммммммммммммм

Comment: Ничего не понятно.